# Unique/No Duplicated values in Shell Array Linux

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, duplicates, unique

I need to make a new array or just delete from the actual array the duplicate elements,

```
#The NTP IPS are the following ones:
#10.30.10.0, 10.30.10.0, 10.30.20.0, 10.30.20.0, 10.30.20.0

#!/bin/bash
ips_networks=()
for ip in ${ips_for_ntp[@]};do
    ips_networks+=${ip%.*}.0
done
```

So I'll get ips_networks with duplicate ips, but I need just one of each ip into another array or the same, I have try with awk, set -A (Is not working on my linux), cut but with no luck, is there anyway to make an unique value array?

Comment: It is `declare -A` for an associative array not `set -A` and it needs bash 4+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ips="10.30.10.0, 10.30.10.0, 10.30.20.0, 10.30.20.0, 10.30.20.0"
unique_ips=`echo $ips | sed -e "s/\s\\+//g" | sed -e "s/,/\\n/g"| sort | uniq`
echo $unique_ips #10.30.10.0 10.30.20.0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but using the comma to separate, the thing is this ips are already in the array "ips_networks" so if make a echo it will be like this:
10.30.10.010.30.10.010.30.20.010.30.20.010.30.20.0